# Who standardizes the JavaScript language

Tags: javascript

As I understand it, ECMA International is responsible for defining the ECMAScript language specification (Reference number ECMA 262). This specification is implemented by certain languages, such as JavaScript or ActionScript. These languages are then transformed into a machine-readable form through an engine, such as V8 or SpiderMonkey.

What is still unclear for me is **who is responsible for standardizing the JavaScript language itself**? How is it possible that everybody writes the same JavaScript code if only the specification upon with the language is based seems to be standardized?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure that "the specification" means a *complete* description of how the language behaves. The specification *is* the language.

Comment: How is it possible that ActionScript is also based on the same specification as JavaScript but is still not exactly the same?

Comment: Implementors can add things to their implementation of the specification. Think of the specification as a minimum. Everything in the specification is in ActionScript (assuming is conforms to the specification), plus whatever else the implementation adds. Same with Node.js, it does more than the specification, too.

Comment: I've never actually come across ActionScript - but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) it's a superset of JS, rather than a truly different language. That is, it must do everything that JS does, with some additional functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is being specified by a group of people called [TC39](https://tc39.es/). This group belongs to the ECMA international organization (Ecma International - European association for standardizing information and communication systems).

The specification is being developed publicly [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/).

Features find their way into the specification according to the [TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/).

Discussions around proposals and the Javascript language also take place in a [mailing group](https://esdiscuss.org/).

Comment: What is the difference between the "ECMAScript specification" and the specification that TC39 is working on?

Comment: @JesterWest No difference. TC39 works on proposals, which eventually undergo the aforementioned process and finally become part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

**TC39** means Technical Committee number 39. It is part of ECMA, the institution which standardizes the JavaScript language under the “ECMAScript” specification. It works on the standardization of the general purpose, cross platform, vendor-neutral programming language that is ECMAScript. This includes the language syntax, semantics, libraries, and complementary technologies that support the language.

**TC39** and the W3C collaborate wherever there is overlap between JavaScript and HTML5.

**TC39** has bi-monthly face to face meetings, usually on the West Coast but one meeting per year takes place in Europe. In addition, at least one meeting is held in Redmond, WA (July meeting usually).

Attendance at meetings is controlled by Ecma International By-laws and Rules. Visitors on a one-time basis are usually approved by the Secretary General and requests should be directed to him for approval. Such visitors are kindly invited to fill in the Ecma International TC39 ECMAScript RFTG Contributor form.

**TC 39 works on:**

- Maintaining and updating the standard for the ECMAScript programming language.
- Identifying, developing and maintaining standards for libraries that extend the capabilities of ECMAScript.
- Developing test suites that may be used to verify correct implementation of these standards.
- Contributing with selected standards to the ISO/IEC JTC 1 committee.
- Evaluating and considering proposals for complementary or additional technologies.

[Reference Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tc39-and-its-contributions-to-ecmascript-c178b77f32e1/)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Actionscript - Adobe were much more proactive in adding features than the rest of the wwwc were at the time, this led to the creation of Actionscript 3.0, based on  ECMA script version 4, which was never implemented for browser JS, which was a shame, though they were focusing on aligning ES5 with HTML5, and saving many of the ES4 proposed features for ES6 like the Class syntax, though this is still optional and legacy code is still compatible. While ES4/AS3 had mandatory class structure, and was gravitating to becoming a more like Java than Javascript, and consequentially, wasn't backwards compatible, which was a dealbreaker for the consortium.

So to answer your question - how can they be different? it's because the spec doesn't necessarily make it off the drawing board in all cases, and there's no mandate for a proprietary Language like Actionscript to stick to any standard, whilst JS should continue to adhere to them.

(Historically, Microsoft have tried to rock the boat, with jscript and it's proprietary features, and now Typescript with more of the same, but now JS is becoming a compile target, it allows companies like Microsoft to rock the boat as much as they want without getting in the way of the wwwc. Where we will still see disparity moving forward will be different languages compiling to JS, and JS compliant standards like webassembly that aren't built for human readability become more commonplace, but that's answering a whole other question.)